# Django Attribute Error: 'function' object has no attribute 'is_usable'

Tags: python, django, zinnia

Django Attribute Error: 'function' object has no attribute 'is_usable'

I am setting up a Django blog. I followed [these instructions](http://django-blog-zinnia.readthedocs.org/en/v0.14/getting-started/install.html#urls) and I am getting the following error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://url.com/

Django Version: 1.6.2
Python Version: 2.7.3
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'south',
 'divinare',
 'rest_framework',
 'django_facebook',
 'django.contrib.auth')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/spencer/webapps/hello_django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  139.                 response = response.render()
File "/home/spencer/webapps/hello_django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  105.             self.content = self.rendered_content
File "/home/spencer/webapps/hello_django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  80.         template = self.resolve_template(self.template_name)
File "/home/spencer/webapps/hello_django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in resolve_template
  56.             return loader.select_template(template)
File "/home/spencer/webapps/hello_django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in select_template
  180.             return get_template(template_name)
File "/home/spencer/webapps/hello_django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in get_template
  138.     template, origin = find_template(template_name)
File "/home/spencer/webapps/hello_django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in find_template
  121.             loader = find_template_loader(loader_name)
File "/home/spencer/webapps/hello_django/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in find_template_loader
  104.         if not func.is_usable:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /
Exception Value: 'function' object has no attribute 'is_usable'
```

Middleware:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    #'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

Template Loaders:

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)
```

Any insights to what is causing the error would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is almost certainly that you have "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth" in your `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` setting. As the name implies, that's a context processor, not a template loader - it should go in [`TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#std%3asetting-TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS).

Comment: Yes that was it, I am not completely sure how I managed to put that in there.